# How to change display:block to display:none using only SCSS?

Tags: html, css, sass, megamenu

I have navigation with a mega menu. If I click on "option 1", I need to set `display: block` on `list-1`. If I click on "option 2", I need to set `display: none` on `list-1` and `display: block` on `list-2`.

Here is an example of the megamenu:

```
<div>
    <ul>
       <li class="option-1"><a>option 1</a></li>
       <li class="option-2"><a>option 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-1">
       <li>option</li>
       <li>option</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-2">
       <li>option</li>
       <li>option</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this using only SCSS or CSS?

Comment: The only way to apply a style and keep it applied onclick is to use a bit of JavaScript.

Comment: you could probably hack it with a checkbox or similar, but may I ask why you don't want to use JS?

Comment: Tnx @avia, I need to build the webapp very light, so i cant use JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative is to use JS or jQuery like below:

```js
$('.list').hide();
$('.button-1').click(function() {
   $('.list').hide();
   $('.list-1').toggle();
});
$('.button-2').click(function() {
  $('.list').hide();
   $('.list-2').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button-1">1</button>
<button class="button-2">2</button>


    <ul class="list-1 list">
       <li>option1</li>
       <li>option1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-2 list">
       <li>option2</li>
       <li>option2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess at the end I must use JS for this.

Comment: well, technically speaking you could style a checkbox into a "button" and use code like the one in my 2nd answer.

Comment: Yes but in that way i need to show the ckeckboxes.

Comment: Well yes and no, you could probably style them enough to get some kind of a 'button' effect, if that's what you want, of make them look like a regular div/span. This is a pretty cool resource to get started : https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/ But if you do 'hack' the checkboxes with CSS (or else), make sure to verify compatibility with all major browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding completely JS/jQuery, you could style a checkbox into a "button" and use code like this one.

```css
.option-1:checked ~ .list-1 {
  display:none;
}

.option-2:checked ~ .list-2 {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input class="option-1" type="checkbox">
<input class="option-2" type="checkbox">



<ul class="list-1">
  <li>1</li><li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-2">
  <li>3</li><li>4</li>
</ul>
```